# vector::size and Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, size, segmentation-fault

Why could this code throw segmentation fault?:/

```
listeners = new vector<Listener*> ();

... /* other code */

if (listeners != NULL) {
int i = listeners->size();
}
```

Comment: Well, the contents of the three dots are critically important. Your code sample does not reproduce the problem in any way, so how could we possibly be expected to determine the problem?

Comment: @Mart: You will have to paste the code. I would guess that the vector was deleted at some point, and hence you are dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Comment: I get the feeling the 3 dots are somehow important here.

Comment: A pointer can be non-NULL and still be invalid.

Comment: To add to this, I would write something like listeners = shared_ptr<vector<Listener*>>(new vector<Listener *>()), instead :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the pointer isn't `NULL` doesn't mean it points to a valid `vector<Listener*>` object.

Run your program through *valgrind* to detect memory corruption issues, and make sure that you run your code through your debugger, too.

If you still have problems, post a test that reproduces the issue (rather than little snippets of code that do not).

Comment: Valgrind helps... problem was on deleting object from memory.... but still trying handling it with another pointer which didnt knew about delete

Answer (score 1):

Easier than using valgrind is to move the `listeners->size()` call right after the allocation and see if it segfaults even then. If no, move it a few lines of code lower and try again, repeat. If it segfaults, you just found the lines that cause it. Maybe you have done something with the pointer along the way and this is a method to find that piece of code.
Look at the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

May not work always, it's more of a heuristic.

Comment: line which cause segmentation fault is:
int i = listeners->size();

Comment: Yes, but try to move the line that causes the segfault up. Let's say there is some code in the dots that causes the listeners->size() to segfault, maybe you did something ugly with the pointer.

Comment: @Mart - Which means that `listeners` is invalid there. Move the line up into the `...` section until it is no longer invalid. Then you have come closer to where the real problem is, and can look at the intervening code.

Comment: As you indicate, this is _not_ a reliable approach. UB may or may not result in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<Listener*> listeners;` might save you some problems or make the reason of the code break more evident